# How to "fix all HTML tag width"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

whenever web application open any device then width set first time, all tags width don't change.
it must not be changed HTML all tags width.

```css
body{ 
  min-width: 1124px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>size check</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      hkjhjk
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      kjghkjkj
    </div>
    <section>
      The online encyclopedia project Wikipedia is by far the most popular wiki-based website, and is one of the most widely viewed sites of any kind in the world, having been ranked in the top ten since 2007.[3] Wikipedia is not a single wiki but rather a collection of hundreds of wikis, one for each language. There are at least tens of thousands of other wikis in use, both public and private, including wikis functioning as knowledge management resources, notetaking tools, community websites and intranets. The English-language Wikipedia has the largest collection of articles; as of September 2016, it had over five million articles. Ward Cunningham, the developer of the first wiki software, WikiWikiWeb, originally described it as "the simplest online database that could possibly work".[4] "Wiki" (pronounced [ˈwiki][note 1]) is a Hawaiian word meaning "quick".
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: does it changes automatically for you? wired

Comment: sir, that is my web application  http://www.project.hariomtech.com/price_comp/  as that application size to shrink prevent as like flipkart    https://www.flipkart.com/

Comment: i want to prevent application size shrinking fixed size. don't be changed

Comment: and also layout of page

Comment: Hi, I have a wordpress website which I don't want to be responsive. I have a separate theme for mobile, so I don't want my desktop website to be responsive.
I think I have to do this using media queries but I am unable to manage this.

Can someone please help on this?

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWJadK

Comment: I am still getting same problem http://www.project.hariomtech.com/price_comp/     that is my web application link , i don't want to be responsive such as flipkart website  https://www.flipkart.com